# Mail Server with Google Apps

Tags: linux, email, email-server, gmail

Is there any mail server that has a feature to download (POP3) emails from another mail server like Google Apps (Gmail for your own domain), store it and then allow to users to download (POP3/IMAP) emails to their own mail client like Outlook/Live Mail? So I want it to become like a "middle mail server".

I hope you guys understand it. My main reason to do so is that Google Apps got limited space for each mailbox and I also want to have emails in one space so its easy to archive and backup.

Comment: 7500MB per mail box is not enough?

Comment: is not for my business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fetchmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetchmail) in conjunction with your normal MTA

Google finds [examples](http://www.axllent.org/docs/networking/gmail_pop3_with_fetchmail)

Answer (score 0):

For an inexpensive setup I'd recommend using Mdaemon from [ALT-N](http://www.altn.com/). The domain pop feature sounds like what you're looking for. They have a free 5 user setup and their higher end versions scale pretty well on price/performance.

Answer (score 0):

popcon for Exchange 2007/2010
http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm

It can download email from any pop account to a Exchange Mailbox, your users can then connect to Exchange to get there email.

Hope that Helps